# How to launch UI application using service for each new session?

Tags: c#, windows, service, ipc, launch

I have backend application (service) that needs to launch and communicate with a C# desktop UI application (both on the same machine).
So far everything is fine.

I want to know how to launch the UI application using the service if a new session opened (another user logged in and the first or previous users didn't log off **OR** not - all the options)?

UPDATE:

The service should launch the UI application for each session.

The end point is to have more control over the UI app 'life', launch the UI app as not killable and in case the user did manage to shut it down, I want to relaunch the UI app using the service.

Thanks

Comment: Windows is a multi-user OS. There is no such thing as a *"current session"*. You first need to understand the problem you are trying to solve to solve it.

Comment: I'll rephrase the problem : "how to launch the UI app for each new opened session using service". You can ignore the "current session" part.
Right now the UI app is registered under 'Startup registry', I want the service to launch the UI app for each new session.

Comment: What issue are you trying to solve by starting the client application from the service, instead of using your current solution? Besides that, don't put edits in comments. Update your question instead.

Comment: I want to be able to relaunch the UI app in case of the user shut it down.